# Problem while defining a function in a `for` loop in Python

Tags: python, function, functools

I have the following minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
def f1(a, b):
    print(1)
    return a + b


def f2(a, b):
    print(2)
    return a * b


funcs = f1, f2


_funcs = []
for func in funcs:

    def _func(x):
        return func(*x)

    _func.__name__ = func.__name__
    _funcs.append(_func)
funcs = _funcs


for func in funcs:
    print(func([2, 3]))
```

This throws a `TypeErro`:

> TypeError: _func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

with the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-93-e24e67b5e525> in <module>()
     22 
     23 for func in funcs:
---> 24     print(func([2, 3]))

<ipython-input-93-e24e67b5e525> in _func(x)
     14 
     15     def _func(x):
---> 16         return func(*x)
     17 
     18     _func.__name__ = func.__name__

TypeError: _func() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am not sure why as it seems to me that `_func()` is always called with a single argument.

I suspect what I want to do would be done with `functools`, but still I fail to see why the above code works this way. Any hint?

Comment: Very strange, and when you type `print(funcs[0]([2, 4]))` and `print(funcs[1]([2, 4]))` (so outside the `for` loop) in both case, I get `2` and `8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing over the free-variable `func` when you define:

```
def _func(x):
    return func(*x)
```

However, in your loop, you re-using this name,

```
for func in funcs:
    print(func([2, 3]))
```

So `func` now refers to the single-argument functions you defined, *even inside `_func`*! So of course, when that function calls `func(*x)` it's actually recursively calling itself. Use a different name:

```
for f in funcs:
    print(f([2, 3]))
```

Or better yet, don't rely on a free-variable you don't intend to be free:

```
def func_maker(func):
    def _func(x):
        return func(*x)
    return _func
```

And use that:

```
...

_funcs = []
for func in funcs:

    _func = func_maker(func)

    _func.__name__ = func.__name__
    _funcs.append(_func)
funcs = _funcs

...
```

Comment: See also: [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: @0x5453 yes, it's the same fundamental issue, although, I think in this case it isn't as obvious. I had to look it over a couple of times.